# Classifying critical points

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to use a second derivative test and I am stuck on how to proceed.

Below is how far I have gotten on the question:

[image]

[image]

This is my solution using an online graphing tool:
I am still unsure how to do this mathematically.

[image]

Comment: So $f(x,y) = (xy)e^{-x^2-y^4}$?

Comment: @bluesh34 I am pretty confused about that too... When I downloaded this question it looked exactly how I posted it but I think there might have been some issue with the PDF which took out the square root..But I think you are right.

Comment: Well you've taken $f(x,y) = (xy)e^{-2x-4y}$. Your next step is to solve the system $$f_x = 0$$  $$f_y=0$$

Comment: @bluesh34 that is the problem...I cant figure out how to isolate x and y when I get the partial derivatives to 0.

Comment: see my answer @Raynos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At critical points, we have the following system:
$$f_x=0$$
$$f_y=0$$
Assuming you want to know about $f(x,y) = (xy)e^{-2x-4y}$ rather than $f(x,y) = (xy)e^{-x^2-y^4}$, this means
$$(y-2xy)e^{-2x-4y} = 0$$
$$(x-4xy)e^{-2x-4y} = 0$$
which means
$$y(1-2x) = 0$$ (1)
$$x(1-4y) = 0$$ (2)

since $e^{-2x-4y}$ is never $0$.

From (1),

$y = 0$ or $x = \frac{1}{2}$

Substituting $y = 0$ into (2) gives
$$x = 0$$  so we have a critical point at $(0,0)$

Substituting $x = \frac{1}{2}$ into (2) gives
$$y = \frac{1}{4}$$

so the other critical point is $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4})$

Now just compute $$D(a,b) = f_{xx}(a,b)f_{yy}(a,b) - {[f_{xy}(a,b)]}^2$$ for each point to classify it:

If $D(a,b) \gt 0$ and $f_{xx}(a,b) \gt 0$ there's a relative minimum at $(a,b)$

If $D(a,b) \gt 0$ and $f_{xx}(a,b) \lt 0$ there's a relative maximum at $(a,b)$

If $D(a,b) \lt 0$ there's a saddle point at $(a,b)$

If $D(a,b) = 0$ then the point $(a,b)$ may be a relative minimum, relative maximum or a saddle point. Other techiniques would be needed to find out which.

Comment: Your partial derivatives are wrong.  There a five critical points.

Comment: good point @Michael

Comment: I was taking $f(x,y) = (xy)e^{-2x-4y}$, as the asker of the question did when working out the partial derivatives. Obviously this doesn't agree with the computer answer, which is solving $f(x,y) = (xy)e^{-x^2-y^4}$ @Michael Hoppe

Comment: How come there are 5 critical points? I typed into the graphing calculator at wolfram and it says just one local max at (1/2,1/4)

Comment: There is some confusion over whether we are talking about  $f(x,y) = (xy)e^{-2x-4y}$ or $f(x,y) = (xy)e^{-x^2-y^4}$. The former has 2 critical points, the latter appears to have 5. Your computer answer (which refers to the latter) seems to have left out (0,0), giving only 4 critical points.

Comment: could (0,0) be a saddle point?

Comment: Don't know: I'd need to analyse it. It could be unclassifiable using the D(x,y) test (if D(x,y) = 0).

Comment: I've just checked, and yes, (0,0) is a saddle point for $f(x,y) = (xy)e^{-x^2-y^4}$. Sorry to take so long: I had a mental block when finding one of the critical points.

Comment: @Raynos Of course the origin is a saddle since $D(0,0)=-1$.

Comment: Yes. This is actually true for both $f(x,y) = (xy)e^{-2x-4y}$ and $f(x,y) = (xy)e^{-x^2-y^4}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Assuming

$$f(x,y)=xye^{-x^2-y^4}\;:$$

$$\begin{align*}f'_x&=ye^{-x^2-y^4}\left(1-2x^2\right)=0\iff\begin{cases}y=0&,\;\text{or}\\{}\\x=\pm\frac1{\sqrt2}\end{cases}\\{}\\f'_y&=xe^{-x^2-y^4}\left(1-4y^4\right)=0\iff\begin{cases}x=0&,\;\text{or}\\{}\\y=\pm\frac1{\sqrt2}\end{cases}\\{}\\
f_{xy}'&=(1-2x^2)e^{-x^2-y^4}\left(1-4y^4\right)\\{}\\
f_{x^2}'&=-2xye^{-x^2-y^4}\left(3+2x^2\right)\end{align*}$$

etc.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Take the first derivative using the product rule three times along with the chain rule. Repeat to obtain the second derivative. Set $y$ to 0. Solve for $x$.